# Please stop using DoD to refer to the U.S. Department of Defense

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editing

Please stop using DoD to refer to the U.S. Department of Defense. DOD is part of their brand.

[**Use of Name**](https://www.defense.gov/Brand-Guide/#:~:text=AP%20Stylebook%20rules.-,Use%20of%20Name,alone%20acronym%20suffices%20depending%20upon%20use.%20Do%20NOT%20use%20%E2%80%9CDoD.%E2%80%9D,-Use%20of%20DOD)

> "U.S. Department of Defense" and "Department of Defense" refer to the proper name and legal entity of this cabinet-level government department. Reserve these for use in formal and official correspondence, documents, reports and testimony.
>
> In all other cases, use "Defense Department" on first reference.
>
> The correct acronym for "Defense Department" is "DOD" with a capitalized "O" in the center; use on second reference after "Defense Department" or when the stand-alone acronym suffices depending upon use. Do NOT use "DoD."

Interestingly, the [U.S. Government Publishing Office Style Manual](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2016/pdf/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2016.pdf#page=254) (GPO) 2016 uses the following:

- DOC—Department of Commerce
- DoD—Department of Defense
- DOE—Department of Energy
- DOI—Department of the Interior
- DOJ—Department of Justice
- DOL—Department of Labor
- DoS—Department of State
- DOT—Department of Transportation

But congress.gov uses DOD in legislation printed by the GPO:

- [H.R.185](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/185) - Veterans Affairs Transfer of Information and Sharing of Disability Examination Procedures With DOD Doctors Act
- [H.R.2005](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/2005) - DOD Entrepreneurial Innovation Act

Note that, like the Defense Department, the U.S. Department of State also has a [Brand System](https://brand.america.gov/), but that site is not yet complete.

Comment: Isn't DoD commonly used as well? For example in [this manual for written material, also by DoD](https://biotech.law.lsu.edu/blaw/dodd/corres/pdf/51104m_030204/p51104m.pdf) [sic]. Maybe this rebrand is more recent, the document I'm referring to is dated March 2004.

Comment: @JJJ - Maybe it's recent. but DOD now says use this to identify the organization.

Comment: Yea, I get where you're coming from but I'm not sure to what extent we should keep up to date with these rebrands. For example, do you  propose editing new posts when they use the old style? What about existing posts? Isn't it a bit like [US vs British English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23869)? Both are commonly used (and some style guides prescribe one over the other) but it's SE policy not to enforce style so strictly except in tags.

Comment: In the end context will let people know what is being talked about regardless of it being DoD or DOD or even dod.

Comment: @JJJ - The quoted text in https://politics.stackexchange.com/revisions/68855/2 was changed from DOD to DoD. That should not have happened, but note that the title of the article used DoD and the text used DOD twice. My point is that one should not be changed to the other and **users should prefer DOD, hence the "Please"**. Recall https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3924/26455 concerning capitalization of president. Some edits were made. They should not be made regarding DOD.

Comment: @RickSmith the purpose of that edit was since the quoted text used DoD, I wanted it to be consistent.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica that article uses DOD in the body, but DoD in the title. Please double check before changing quotes, it's very unlikely someone would copy paste and then change a minor detail like that.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica - There is and has been a lot of inconsistency in Politics SE regarding DoD versus DOD. There are 60 posts on this site containing a mix of both, including an earlier one that used both in the same answer. Respectfully, there was no need to change the quote, but when doing so, it is common practice to enclose the change in square brackets to show that the text was altered.

Comment: @JoeW - "dod" will be changed if the question is edited, and may actually trigger an edit. It will be changed to one or the other depending on the editor.

Comment: My point was it would still be understandable what was being talked about, not if someone would change it.

Comment: @JJJ and #RickSmith my bad, I’ve undone the quote edit I did earlier (but left the note in there).

Answer (score 7):

The brand guide does not have any particular authority for Stack Exchange contributors, any more than a company's brand guide does.  Branding guidelines are supposed to govern how people associated with a brand (employees, partners, and so on) present the brand to outside parties.  They have no bearing on how other people refer to the brand.  For example, if Microsoft's branding guidelines say not to refer to the company as MS, that doesn't stop anyone from referring to the company as MS in a Stack Exchange post.

From the DoD's branding guidelines:

> The purpose of this guide is to ensure that no matter how people engage with the DOD – on the website, via email or U.S. mail, through social media, livestream broadcasts or photographs – they are left with an impression that accurately reflects the department’s brand identity and mission.

Readers of this site are not engaging with the Defense Department.  Contributors to this site have no responsibility to reflect the department's preferred brand identity.

> The department shares the DOD story daily through official statements and a variety of informational products, engaging with many audiences around the world.

Contributors to this site are not sharing the department's story, making official department statements, nor creating informational products on the department's behalf.

Comment: Having a preference for DOD over DoD is a matter *respect* -- same for Microsoft over MS. *They* is not a third-person singular pronoun, but is used out of respect. I didn't ask for any more than that. Simply respect their choice.

Comment: @RickSmith - I don't think that using an abbreviation for a company rises to nearly the same level of disrespect as misgendering someone. A brand guide is meant to ensure coherent brand identity for organizational recognition purposes, not ensure that a company's preferred name is respected by the public, as clear in the document that you linked. I doubt that the New York Times brand guide says that it's acceptable to call it the Gray Lady in stories or letterhead, and I equally doubt that it's emotionally hurtful to almost anyone at the paper that people outside the company employ the term.